# Does AWS DMS supports data migration from GCP Cloud server to AWS MySQL Aurora?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds, aws-dms, amazon-aurora

I am not finding clear AWS DMS documentation from migrating cloud (GCP) SQL server to AWS Aurora MySQL though, AWS provided on-premise and RDS as source but not GCP SQL server as source in documentation. So, my question is does DMS supports GCP sql server to AWS Aurora MySQL with full load + ongoing replication changes?  any ideas please?

Comment: Are you trying to migrate Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL? If yes, you will need third party tools. Google search for a vendor to help you. Note: depending on your table design, and features used, there is no simple migration path. Those databases are very different.

Comment: Does AWS SCT (Schema conversion Toll) won't help?

Comment: It depends. Read the SCT documentation.